# Rendering from a single document in Firestore database with React [forEach error]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My current database structure is:

courses (collection) -> testcourse (document) -> *Fields with course information in*

I am trying to read the course information without it looping through all of the courses, I only want the data from the testcourse document however, when I use the .doc method to try and get it, it doesn't render anything due to a 'forEach' error.

How would I take the forEach out? Can I do so?

I'm quite new to both React and Firebase so sorry if this seems like a stupid question!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../../CourseStyles/CourseInformation.scss';
import placeholderimg from '../../../Public/Assets/placeholderimage.png';


const firebase = require("firebase");


export default class CourseInformation extends Component {

    state = {
        courses: null
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const db = firebase.firestore();

        db.collection('courses').doc('testcourse').get().then((snapshot)=>{
            const courseData = []
            snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                const data = doc.data()
                this.setState(data)
                courseData.push(data)
                console.log(this.state)
            }) 

            this.setState({courses: courseData})
        })
    }



    render() {
        return (
            <div className = "CourseInformationContainer">
                <div className = "CourseInformationImages">
                    <img src = {placeholderimg} className = "CourseInformationImage"/>
                    <img src = {placeholderimg} className = "CourseInformationImage"/>

                </div>

        <div className = "CourseInformationTextContainer">
                                    <div className = "CourseInformationText">
                                    <h1> {this.state.courseName} </h1>
                                    <p> {this.state.courseDescription}</p>
                                   
                                    <button> Let's Go</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
            
               
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the error that you are facing? Besides that, why are you using a `forEach` if you are getting data only from a single document?

Answer (score 2):

When you use .get() on a document in firebase instead of .onSnapshot() you don't get a snapshot of documents. You get a single document which you can access just by doc.data().
If you want to listen for realtime changes you have to use .onSnapshot().

```
db.collection('courses')
   .doc('testcourse')
    .get()
    .then(doc=>{
     const data = doc.data();
     this.setState(data)           
   });
```

If you want realtime changes use .onSnapshot() method

```
db.collection('courses')
   .doc('testcourse')
    .onSnapshot(doc=>{
       const data = doc.data();

      //do something with data and this function will be called again if a change is dont to the document 
    })
```

and the way you were doing is the way we will listen to the changes of a whole collection.

```
db.collection('courses')
   .onSnapshot(snapshot=>{
     const courseData = []
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
            const data = doc.data()
            this.setState(data)
            courseData.push(data)
            console.log(this.state)
        }) 

        this.setState({courses: courseData})
       })
```

You can read about [get here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) and about onSnapshot [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)